# Do the null hypotheses used for benjamini-hochberg have to be identical?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, statistical-significance

There are some cases where I would like to correct for multiple comparisons where the null hypotheses vary.

For example, if I am performing a chi-squared test or a fisher's exact test on multiple contingency tables of different sizes, the null hypotheses vary from table to table. Can I still apply the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure for multiple comparisons using the p-values from these tests? If not, what should be done in this situation?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no such restriction. The only restriction is whether the tests themselves are independent or not, and there is even some wiggle room there: if the tests are positively correlated, you can pretend they are independent. See e.g [False Discovery Rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) or the references from [Qvalue](http://genomics.princeton.edu/storeylab/qvalue/).